# Can't log in user using wp_sign_on() and set_current_user()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm encountering some trouble trying to setup a login system in wordpress.

I use user inputs from post data to run wp_sign_on(), which returns the user object. I then set the current user using $user->ID;
The problem is that then nothing happens, the user is not logged in. (For example, if I refresh the page or go to another page, I am still not logged in).

I tried to google this issue but none of the solutions fixed it. I am surely missing something. The code works fine but the user isn't actually logged in afterwards...

Code below:

```
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $creds = array();
            $creds['user_login'] = $username;
            $creds['user_password'] = $password;
            $creds['remember'] = true;

            $user = wp_signon( $creds, false ); 
            print_r( $user ); // I can see the user object printed, so it works fine.
            $user_id = $user->id; // I get the user ID
            if ( is_wp_error($user) )
            echo $user->get_error_message();
            else
            {
                wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user_login );
                //The following three lines come from a solution found 
                online, but it doesn't work
                wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
                do_action( 'wp_login', $user_login );
                wp_redirect( remove_query_arg( 'login' ) ); 
                exit; 
            }
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `wp_set_auth_cookie()` function after `wp_set_current_user()`[Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie)